# How to save data using H2 in-memory database?

Tags: grails, h2, in-memory-database

I am working on a grails project and trying to use H2 in-memory database to temporarily save the data coming from the user input. I have added this code: `url = "jdbc:h2:memory"` in my datasource to set up my database. I  created Domain Class that contains two properties. By running the `dbconsole` in my browser, I am able to browse the database I have created, and the table (which corresponds to the class name). I am using the `ClassName.save(flush:true)` to save the data in the in-memory database, but this throws an error, `'No property "database property name" of "class name" is found'`, and when I check the database in the console, nothing is saved.

Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Be aware the in-memory database is discarded, by default, when the connection closes.  You can override this behavior.  See: [*Keep H2 in-memory database between connections*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/224338/19079) and [*H2 in-memory database. Table not found*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5763747/642706)

Answer (score 2):

In my project the configuration string looks different:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
}
```

I believe, you have wrong the "memory" and you are missing the database name (last part of the JDBC string before ";"). Under this string you can also connect to the database via "dbconsole".