# Trivial create, insert with jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to explore the basics of Spring's jdbctemplate. I'm having trouble with a simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
    String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test";
    dataSource.setURL(url);

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    jdbcTemplate.execute("create table something (id int primary key, name varchar(100))");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into something (id, name) values (1, 'Brian')");
}
```

Triggers this:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SOMETHING" not found; SQL statement:
insert into something (id, name) values (1, 'Brian') [42102-177]
```

If I convert that code to use the raw JDBC api, it works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
    String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test";
    dataSource.setURL(url);

    try (Connection dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute("create table something (id int primary key, name varchar(100))");
            statement.execute("insert into something (id, name) values (1, 'Brian')");

            try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select id, name from something")) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("got result. id=%d. name=%s", rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it matters, my Gradle dependencies:

```
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.177'
```

Comment: [Stackoverflow Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763747/h2-in-memory-database-table-not-found) Use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

Answer (score 0):

please try to use `update` method instead `execute`.

Comment: I just tried that. I get the exact same error. To be clear, I changed "execute" to "update" on the "insert" command. FYI, in the raw JDBC version both execute and executeUpdate work.