# H2 JdbcSQLException: "Table not found" with camelcase table & entity name

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

Using Spring Boot, with Spring Data JPA and H2 in-memory database (in PostgreSQL mode if it makes a difference).

I have a table & entity class named `ContentBlock`, yet H2 is complaining about missing `CONTENT_BLOCK` table, when I do a `findAll()` or `findOne()`:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CONTENT_BLOCK" not found
```

I'm not sure if uppercase/camelcase makes a difference, but where does the underscore in `CONTENT_BLOCK` come from?

In my schema definition:

```
CREATE TABLE ContentBlock (
  id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  content  TEXT
  -- etc
);
```

And in the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ContentBlock")
public class ContentBlock {
    // ...
}
```

(Of course I first tried without `@Table` annotation, as the class name exactly matches the table name.)

With my other tables/entities, with names like `Asset`, there are no problems, and I don't need to explicitly specify the table name on Java side:

```
@Entity   
public class Asset {
    // ...
}
```

In my setup, the H2 datasource is explicitly defined like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource devDataSource() {  
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
          .generateUniqueName(true)
          .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
          .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
          .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
          .addScripts("database/init.sql", "database/schema.sql", "database/test_data.sql")
          .build();
    }
```

(Contents of `init.sql` is `SET MODE PostgreSQL;`)

As workaround, I just renamed the `ContentBlock` table to `Block` in `schema.sql`, with `@Table(name = "Block")` in the Java class which I still call `ContentBlock`.

But this is weird, **surely you can map a table with camelcase name to an entity somehow?**

Comment: In reality there are other columns as well, such as foreign key reference to another table, but that is not relavant here; I can reproduce this problem with a simplistic setup like above.

Comment: Maybe put (single) quotes around the names? worth a try perhaps. Some RDBMS use quoting as a way of allowing case sensitivity

Comment: @NeilStockton: Hmm, using single quotes in the CREATE TABLE statement produces a syntax error, but with double quotes I actually get `Table "CONTENTBLOCK" not found` (no underscore!), so you may be onto something here.

Comment: I think this might be solvable using double quotes *and* [`DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17925668/56285). But I'm not sure how to specify that, since I don't explicitly use a H2 connection URL anywhere in the app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `Spring Boot` uses [SpringNamingStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringNamingStrategy.html). It extends `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy` from Hibernate 4. `ImprovedNamingStrategy` generates underscores in table names.

To map a table with camel case name to an entity you can use `org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy` or implement your own.

An example of set a name strategy using properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```