# How to disable H2's DATABASE_TO_UPPER in Spring Boot, without explicit connection URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm aware that H2 has a boolean property/setting called **[`DATABASE_TO_UPPER`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925668/56285)**, which you can set at least in the connection URL, as in: `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false`

I’d like to set this to false, but in my Spring Boot app, **I don’t explicitly have a H2 connection URL** anywhere. Implicitly there sure is a connection URL though, as I can see in the logs:

```
o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory: Shutting down embedded database: 
url='jdbc:h2:mem:2fb4805b-f927-49b3-a786-2a2cac440f44;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'
```

So the question is, what's the easiest way to tell H2 to disable `DATABASE_TO_UPPER` in this scenario? Can I do it in code when creating the H2 datasource with `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` (see below)? Or in `application properties` maybe?

This is how the H2 database is explicitly initialised in code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource devDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
                .addScripts("db/init.sql", "db/schema.sql", "db/test_data.sql")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Also, I'm telling JPA/Hibernate not to [auto-generate embedded database](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) (without this there was an issue that *two* in-memory databases were launched):

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't w\ the `generateUniqueName`, but if you call `setName("testdb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false")` you can add parameters. I doubt this is officially supported, but it worked for me.

The spring code that generates the connection url is like this: 
`String.format("jdbc:h2:mem:%s;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false", databaseName)`

Answer (score 1):

You may want abandon using explicit creation via EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder. Spring Boot creates H2 instance automatically based on configuration. So I would try this in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/testdb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
```