# java h2 in-memory database error: Table not found

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, h2

I tried googling around, but the solution to almost all this kind of questions was to add `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`, however it does not solve anything for me.

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Main.class})
public class Testas {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("managerImplementation")
    private ClassifierManager manager;

    @Test
    public void testManager(){
        ClassifierGroupEntity cge = new ClassifierGroupEntity();
        manager.saveClassifierGroup(cge);
    }
}
```

Manager class

```
@Service("managerImplementation")
public class ClassifierManagerImpl implements ClassifierManager{

    @Autowired
    private ClassifierGroupEntityRepository groupEntityRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ClassifierEntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Autowired 
    private ClassifierValueEntityRepository valueEntityRepository;

    @Override
    public ClassifierGroupEntity getClassifierGroup(long id) {
        return groupEntityRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassifierGroupEntity getClassifierGroup(String code) {
        return groupEntityRepository.findByCode(code);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassifierGroupEntity saveClassifierGroup(ClassifierGroupEntity entity) {
        return groupEntityRepository.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteClassifierGroup(long id) {
        groupEntityRepository.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassifierEntity getClassifier(long id) {
        return entityRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassifierEntity getClassifier(String code) {
        return entityRepository.findByCode(code);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassifierEntity saveClassifier(ClassifierEntity entity) {
        return entityRepository.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteClassifier(long id) {
        entityRepository.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassifierValueEntity getClassifierValue(long id) {
        return valueEntityRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public ClassifierValue getClassifierValue(String classifiedCode, String valueCode) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassifierValueEntity saveClassifierValue(ClassifierValueEntity entity) {
        return valueEntityRepository.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteClassifierValue(long id) {
        valueEntityRepository.delete(id);
    }


}
```

And finally properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.user=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
```

Launching the test throws me

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "CLASSIFIER_GROUP_ENTITY" not found; SQL statement:
insert into classifier_group_entity (id, code, modified_details, modified_time, modified_user_id, order, revision, valid_details, valid_from, valid_till, parent_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-191]
```

I don't know if I should provide anything else, please tell me if I do. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: This means that your H2 in memory database is not initialized. If you are using Hibernate you can use <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/> for tests? If not you could provide sql that will create your schema.

Comment: Where do you initialise your DB? Where do you load the SQL to create the schema (and table)?

Comment: I don't, I guess? I think spring jpa creates them for me. I mean it worked fine for me the first time I was doing it (create interface that extends CrudRepository, and then just ask for it's implementation with @Autowired). Sorry if that sounds stupid, I am fresh to all this stuff.

Comment: Somewhere in your hibernate config you need to enable ability to create schema if missing.  In my hibernate.cfg.xml under /hibernate-configuration/session-factory I have:

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

Which creates tables as needed.  I also use @Table(name="...") on my entities so it knows what table is needed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Table was not found, because there was an error at the start when trying to create it. And the error was due to the fact, that one of the `ClassifierGroupEntity` fields was named 'order', which is one of reserved words in SQL, and thus the generated SQL statement by Spring was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Generic error. The only useful thing was something like "Invalid SQL sentence: ..." few dozens lines above. But then if you see that, I don't think you need any more googling. `Unlikely help others` How is telling people to check their field names unlikely to help others??

Comment: You saved me hours ... Thanks

Comment: oh god, glad I've found your answer

Comment: Thanks, mine was a mis-configuration of hibernate dialect for my test profile and hence the generated ddl statements included some mysql specific ddl statements

Answer (score 23):

Have these properties in your **application.properties** file in the src/**test**/resources folder:

**spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true**

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create**

This has to be over-ridden because it's not kept **create** rather kept **none** or **validate** after the first ddl creation.

Comment: tried all the ways found on the internet and almost gave up. fortunately, decide to try this one as the last, and it works. thank you

Comment: I can't believe this worked! I only added the generate-ddl part and it works.

Answer (score 8):

I always use the below configuration for H2 Database, Flyway, Spring Boot JPA before writing integration tests - https://gist.github.com/vslala/d412156e5840fafa1b9f61aae5b20951

Put below configuration in your `src/test/resources/application.properties` file.

```
# Datasource configuration for jdbc h2
# this is for file based persistent storage
# spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/demo

# For in-memory storage
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=vslala
spring.datasource.password=simplepass
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

# This has to be over-ridden because
# it's not kept create rather kept none or validate after the first ddl creation.
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# This is for FlyWay configuration
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.flyway.schemas=testdb
spring.flyway.user=vslala
spring.flyway.password=simplepass
```

Comment: Voting up!  all I needed was to tell flyway to ignore case
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE;

Comment: @Tinkerbell yeah... that one troubled me as well in the past :D

Comment: I was stucked in same problem from few hours but not found correct solution after searching a lot. Finally thank you for the solution. I added MODE=MySQL  to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I might be a little late to the party, but I faced exactly the same error and I tried pretty much every solution mentioned here and on other websites such as DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1; DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE; IGNORECASE=TRUE

But nothing worked for me.
What worked for me was **renaming data.sql to import.sql**

I found it here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53179547/8219358

**Or**

For Spring Boot 2.4+ use **spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true** in application.properties (mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68086707/8219358)

I realize other solutions are more logical but none of them worked for me and this did.

Comment: THX the import.sql did the job for me to :)

Answer (score 2):

add **spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true**

don't forget to add these values in application.properties/application.yaml file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this after adding a few columns to my table. The persistence generator created a few more fields in my entity.

I noticed this in my logs.

```
ERROR 13691 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table comment
ERROR 13691 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Scale($"0") must not be bigger than precision("-1")
```

It turns out that the when my IDE's persistence generator mapped my TEXT field it gave it a length of -1.

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "address", nullable = true, length = -1)
public String getAddress() {
  return address;
}
```

Removing the length attribute solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while I was writing unit tests for my own application. After many tries, I was not able to get my application test cases running. I was running on version 1.4.191 and then I upgraded to 1.4.196 and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was dumb and forgot to actually put in a **spring.datasource.url**

For some reason JPA doesn't throw an error if it can't find an actual database url. Weird

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use lower case syntax for columns when the query is defined but the columns in the H2 database are defined in the upper case. I was expecting to ignore the case sensitivity but it is not the case with H2 databases.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for this problem -

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IGNORECASE=TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used liquibase to update the data. get the same error, so I used the doule quote " to wrap the table name. it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32177739)

Answer (score 0):

What I found was default springboot is adding underscore to every table name and column name when executing this sqls.

Ex - actial table name -> testTable, springboot is converting this into -> test_table when executing sql.

You can disable this default behaviour by adding following property in your application.yml

```
 spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```