# JpaRepository findAll() returns empty result

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, h2

`JpaRepository` `findAll()` method returns empty result. I am trying to implement rest service by using Spring-boot, h2 database and jpa.

Here is my `schema.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `City` (
  `city_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `city_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`));
```

My `data.sql` file includes :

```
INSERT INTO City (city_id,city_name) VALUES(1,'EDE');
INSERT INTO City (city_id,city_name) VALUES(2,'DRUTEN');
INSERT INTO City (city_id,city_name) VALUES(3,'DELFT');
```

The `City` entity :

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "City")
public class City {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "city_id")
  private Long cityId;

  @Column(name = "city_name")
  private String cityName;

  public Long getCityId() {
    return cityId;
  }

  public void setCityId(Long cityId) {
    this.cityId = cityId;
  }

  public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
  }

  public void setCityName(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
  }

}
```

The `JpaRepository` interface:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long> {

    @Override
    List<City> findAll();
}
```

And here is my `Contoller` class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/city")
public class CityController {
    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/all")
    public List<City> getAllCityList(){
        return cityRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The reference documentation : [Spring doc](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

Comment: Remove your overriden `findAll` there is already one in the `JpaRepository` no need to add it again and disable schema creation by hibernate, as that basically overrides what is done by the `schema.sql` and `data.sql`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed `schema.sql` and `data.sql` and removed overridden `findAll` method but it does not work

Comment: If you remove those files you will have nothing inserted obviously...

Comment: @M.Deinum I added ` spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update ` in `  application.properties ` file and put ` schema.sql ` and ` data.sql ` files in resources again. Then it worked! Thanks a lot. it saved my day : )

Answer (score 7):

You have a `schema.sql` and `data.sql` which are both executed after the `DataSource` has been configured and is ready. Next the `EntityManagerFactory` is created and by default (See [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate)) this will `create-drop` the database for embedded types (like H2).

You can override this behavior by changing the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to anything else then `create` or `create-drop`.

Another solution is to rename your `data.sql` to `import.sql` which will be executed after Hibernate created the schema for you. You can now obviously also remove the `schema.sql` as Hibernate will create the schema.

If this is for learning purposes you should be fine, if you want to use this in a live production system I suggest instead of using this to use something like [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org) to manage your schema.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i understood, you want to execute sql scripts on application startup and after that use Hibernate? Well, you have to use one of the options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data/41644743#41644743), and set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`.The explanation is given there.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the deleted column as null and had @Where(clause = "deleted='false'") on the JPA Entity

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that works for me :

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/sql/schema.sql",
        "spring.datasource.data=classpath:/sql/data.sql",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none"
})
class CalculatorRepositoryTest implements WithAssertions {

    @Autowired
    private CalculatorRepository repository;

    @Test
    void testAutoConfiguration() {
        assertThat(repository).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void testInsertResult() {

        Result newResult = new Result();
        newResult.setOperation(OperationType.DIVISION.name());
        newResult.setValue(10);

        Result insertedResult = repository.save(newResult);

        assertAll(
                () -> assertThat(insertedResult).isNotNull(),
                () -> assertThat(insertedResult.getId()).isEqualTo(5L),
                () -> assertThat(insertedResult.getOperation()).isEqualTo(OperationType.DIVISION.name()),
                () -> assertThat(insertedResult.getValue()).isEqualTo(10)
        );
    }

    @Test
    void testSelectAllResults() {

        List<Result> results = repository.findAll();
        assertAll(
                () -> assertThat(results).isNotEmpty(),
                () -> assertThat(results.get(0).getOperation()).isEqualTo(OperationType.ADDITION.name()),
                () -> assertThat(results.get(0).getValue()).isEqualTo(5)
        );

    }

}
```

**`schema.sql`**

```
CREATE TABLE result(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    operation VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    value INT
);
```

**`data.sql`**

```
INSERT INTO result(id, operation, value) VALUES(1, 'ADDITION', 5);
INSERT INTO result(id, operation, value) VALUES(2, 'SUBTRACTION', 14);
INSERT INTO result(id, operation, value) VALUES(3, 'MULTIPLICATION', 10);
INSERT INTO result(id, operation, value) VALUES(4, 'DIVISION', 3);
```

First fo all you don't need to override the `findAll()` method. It is already available in your interface.

While configuring your `schema.sql` and `data.sql` file, the first thing to do is to set this propertie `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none`, to avoid hibernate create the schema for you.

```
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/sql/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/sql/data.sql
```

Here my `sql` files are in this location : `test/resources/sql`. Otherwise, by default, you don't need those configurations if you put your file in `test/resources`

You can find **very good** details on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data).