# Spring JDBC using application.properties file

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc

I'm training myself on *Spring JDBC* and I'm following this tutorial: [Spring JDBC Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm).

The tutorial is very good and executing the code I have no problem.

Fof simplicity and convenience, I quote here the code.

First class, Student (the entity to store in db):

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class Student 
{
       private Integer age;
       private String name;
       private Integer id;

       public void setAge(Integer age) 
       {
          this.age = age;
       }
       
       public Integer getAge() 
       {
          return age;
       }
       
       public void setName(String name) 
       {
          this.name = name;
       }
       
       public String getName() 
       {
          return name;
       }
       
       public void setId(Integer id) 
       {
          this.id = id;
       }
       
       public Integer getId() 
       {
          return id;
       }
    }
```

Interface, `StudentDAO` (for *DAO* logic):

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public interface StudentDAO 
{
   /** 
      * This is the method to be used to initialize
      * database resources ie. connection.
   */
   public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);
   
   /** 
      * This is the method to be used to create
      * a record in the Student table.
   */
   public void create(String name, Integer age);
   
   /** 
      * This is the method to be used to list down
      * a record from the Student table corresponding
      * to a passed student id.
   */
   public Student getStudent(Integer id);
   
   /** 
      * This is the method to be used to list down
      * all the records from the Student table.
   */
   public List<Student> listStudents();
   
   /** 
      * This is the method to be used to delete
      * a record from the Student table corresponding
      * to a passed student id.
   */
   public void delete(Integer id);
   
   /** 
      * This is the method to be used to update
      * a record into the Student table.
   */
   public void update(Integer id, Integer age);
}
```

Then, the class `StudentJDBCTemplate` (to implements `StudentDAO`):

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO 
{
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
   
   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) 
   {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
      this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }
   
   public void create(String name, Integer age) 
   {
      String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, name, age);
      System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);
      return;
   }
   
   public Student getStudent(Integer id) 
   {
      String SQL = "select * from Student where id = ?";
      Student student = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, 
         new Object[]{id}, new StudentMapper());
      
      return student;
   }
   
   public List<Student> listStudents() 
   {
      String SQL = "select * from Student";
      List <Student> students = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new StudentMapper());
      return students;
   }
   
   public void delete(Integer id) 
   {
      String SQL = "delete from Student where id = ?";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
      System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id );
      return;
   }
   
   public void update(Integer id, Integer age)
   {
      String SQL = "update Student set age = ? where id = ?";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, age, id);
      System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id );
      return;
   }
}
```

Third class: `StudentMapper` (to mapping to *MySQL* db `Student`):

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

public class StudentMapper implements RowMapper<Student> 
{
   public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException 
   {
      Student student = new Student();
      student.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
      student.setName(rs.getString("name"));
      student.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
      
      return student;
   }
}
```

Last class, `MainApp` (run the application):

```
  package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = 
         (StudentJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTemplate");
      
      System.out.println("------Records Creation--------" );
      studentJDBCTemplate.create("Zara", 11);
      studentJDBCTemplate.create("Nuha", 2);
      studentJDBCTemplate.create("Ayan", 15);

      System.out.println("------Listing Multiple Records--------" );
      List<Student> students = studentJDBCTemplate.listStudents();
      
      for (Student record : students) {
         System.out.print("ID : " + record.getId() );
         System.out.print(", Name : " + record.getName() );
         System.out.println(", Age : " + record.getAge());
      }

      System.out.println("----Updating Record with ID = 2 -----" );
      studentJDBCTemplate.update(2, 20);

      System.out.println("----Listing Record with ID = 2 -----" );
      Student student = studentJDBCTemplate.getStudent(2);
      System.out.print("ID : " + student.getId() );
      System.out.print(", Name : " + student.getName() );
      System.out.println(", Age : " + student.getAge());
   }
}
```

Finally, the *Beans* file to configure database connection:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

   <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtraining"/>
      <property name = "username" value = "***"/>
      <property name = "password" value = "***"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
   <bean id = "studentJDBCTemplate" 
      class = "com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate">
      <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource" />    
   </bean>
      
</beans>
```

The tutorial is very clear and if i try it, there is a perfect execution without error and the *MySQL* Db is correctly updated.

My questions are about a possible variation of this project. More specifically:

1. If I want to use the `application.properties` file (as that given by *SpringBoot*), is it this the correct syntax?

   `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`
   `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtraining`
   `spring.datasource.username=***`
   `spring.datasource.password=***`
2. If I don't want use the `RowMapper` class, is it correct to use the one given by *Spring*, the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`?
3. Without the *Beans* file (if I use, for this example, the `application.properties`, I have no need of it), how can I replace in the `MainApp` this rows:

   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

   ```
      StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = 
         (StudentJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTemplate");
   ```

and making so the applications executable?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd advise you to learn how to do it without `application.properties` file. We live in 21rst century, where `Spring-boot` allows us to declare jdbc `dataSource` as `@Bean` with database credentials in `MySpringBootApplication` class. See how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data/41644743#41644743)

Secondly, i'd advise not to use `jdbcTemplate` unless you don't have time. Mark my words, if happens to debug - it would be nightmare. So try to use 
pure Jdbc with addition of spring configuration.

Sample example how to do it:

**StudentDAO interface**

```
    public interface StundentDAO {

    void addStudent(String name, String surname);

    List<Student> findStudents();
}
```

**JdbcStudentDAO implementation**

```
    @Repository
    public class JdbcStudentDAO implements StudentDAO {

    //[IMPORTANT] import javax.sql.datasource package (?)
    private Datasource datasource;

    @Autowire
    public JdbcStudentDAO(Datasource datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addStudent(String name, String surname) {
        String query = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES (?,?)";
        try(Connection connection = datasource.getConnection()) {
            try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.preparedStatement(query)) {
                statement.setString(1, name);
                statement.setString(2, surname);
                statement.executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> findStudents() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Students";
        Student student = null; //will be used soon as DTO
        List<Student> listOfStudents = null;
        try(Connection connection = datasource.getConnection()) {
            try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.preparedStatement(query)) {
                try(ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
                    listOfStudents = new ArrayList<>();
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        student = new Student(
                            rs.getString("name");
                            rs.getString("surname");
                        );
                    }
                    listOfStudents.add(student);
                }
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return listOfStudents;
    }
}
```

Please note, that `dataSource` does only Database connectivity.(see the link)

Good luck!

Comment: First of all, tnx for the response. 

Then, i khnow that we have Spring Boot but, for some reason, my boss may don't want use Boot, so i have searched a method withput it.

Anyway, your response is clear and complete and i appreciate very muach.