# Spring Boot Data Initialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to insert some test data after my Spring Boot application has started. I have the below configuration in place. I do notice that the sql script is executed before the JPA entities are created resulting in a failure of the insert statement. Is there any other configuration I am missing here? As noted in my configuration I am using Spring Boot with H2 and EclipseLink for JPA.

**Reference**
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

**Configuration**

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=ORACLE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
# JPA
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.eclipselink.weaving=false
```

**data.sql** is placed under /src/main/resources

**Logs**

```
2017-09-05 20:37:37,989 [restartedMain  ] INFO  
o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory         - Starting embedded database: 
url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', 
username='sa'
2017-09-05 20:37:38,141 [restartedMain  ] INFO  
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  - Building JPA container 
EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-09-05 20:37:38,446 [restartedMain  ] INFO  
o.s.o.j.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean  - Initialized JPA 
EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-09-05 20:37:38,510 [restartedMain  ] INFO  o.s.j.d.i.ScriptUtils                     
- Executing SQL script from URL  [file:/develop/src/data-init/target/classes/data.sql]
error...
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMPLATE_CONFIG")
@Data
public class TemplateUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TEMPLATE_CONFIG_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long configId;

    @Column(name = "APP_CODE", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String appCode;
    ...
}
```

**Update**

Uploaded a sample project:
https://git.io/v5SWx

Comment: Can you post how your entities look like? You need to have them marked with @Entity annotation

Comment: Added the Entity

Comment: Have you tried also setting the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create` property? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-jpa

Comment: Would this matter as I am not using Hibernate?

Comment: you can try to change the datasource url to something like jdbc:h2:mem:testdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Comment: Thanks but that didnt work too :(

Answer (score 0):

Spring-Boot loads data.sql or data-${somthing}.sql

You can do:

- spring.datasource.platform=h2.
- spring.datasource.data=myscript-test.sql. ( locations can be changed  with this property)

I have a project on that way and is working with h2.

And just how last alternative, if you are not able to load the information maybe you can use the CommandLineRunner in your application file with jdbc template.

Comment: I do not have an issue with the loading of data.sql. It is the order in which the sql is run. The sql appears to be run before the Table is created. I have provided a link to a sample project which highlights the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an existing bug in Spring as confirmed here by the Spring Team.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10365