# Loading initial test data in H2 in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.8.Release and writing test cases using H2 in memory database. Currently in each test case class, we have @Before annotation, where we insert data using Spring Data classes.

*I want to know, can I have a single place in project where we can define data for our all test cases.* The database tables are created by Hybernate using entity classes. The only desired thing is about inserting data from single place instead of from @Before in each test case class.

I tried to use *data.sql* containing Insert statements but with it, Spring does not generate schema objects (tables) due to which I get table not found errors. I do not want to specify Create Table statement for each table in schema.sql

**application-test.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: 
  jpa:
    database: h2
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
      naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties: 
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: false
```

**Schema.sql**

```
CREATE SCHEMA AB AUTHORIZATION SA;
```

**AbcControllerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebApp.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class AbcControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  private LeDataService leDataService;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MyInfo myInfo = new MyInfo();
    ..............
    ..............
    leDataService.save(myInfo);
  }

  @Test
  public void getAbcTest() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/v1/Abcs/1234567/12345678")
        .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user("test").password("test123"))
        .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
  }

}
```

Comment: you could look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data/38049582#38049582

Especially this answer applies to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38047021/5371736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create new class annotated with `@Component @Profile({ "dev", "test" })` and that implements `CommandLineRunner` then inject **dependencies**

Override **run()** method with your initial data that came with CommandLineRunner

for example

```
    @Component 
    @Profile({ "dev", "test" })
    setupInitialData implements CommandLineRunner {

    UserService userService;

    //bla bla

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... args) {
       User user = new User;
       user.setName("test");
       userService.save(user);

       //bla bla
    }

 }
```