# How can you load initial data in MongoDB through Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to load initial data in a `MongoDB` database using `src/main/resources/data.sql` or by any other file?

I understand that `data.sql` is used for `SQL` DB's whereas `MongoDB` is a `NOSQL` DB. But just wanted to know if there is any equivalent of `data.sql` for `NOSQL` DB's.

While googling I found out this SO link ([Spring Boot - Loading Initial Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data)) which does what I am looking for but still it's not a standalone file `data.sql`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To load initial data you can use db migration tool like [MongoBee](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee)

It's very useful option to handle data initialization in java. You just need to configure `@Bean public Mongobee mongobee` in your spring boot and setup component scan for data ChangeLogs where data creation actually happens.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a repository populator with Spring Data MongoDB. Let me demonstrate this with a code sample in Kotlin:

```kt
@Configuration
class TestApplicationConfig {
    @Value("classpath:test_data.json")
    private lateinit var testData: Resource

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    fun repositoryPopulator(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean {
        val factory = Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean()
        // inject your Jackson Object Mapper if you need to customize it:
        factory.setMapper(objectMapper)
        factory.setResources(arrayOf(testData))
        return factory
    }
}
```

Put `test_data.json` in resources directory.

Comment: can you take the array from test_data.json and populate it 1 by 1?

Comment: @ShaharWider it looks like a new question. please [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and Stack Overflow will answer.

Comment: i did about 20 days ago. no one answered... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711819/spring-mongo-populator-one-by-one

Answer (score 4):

you can define your data in json/xml and use populator elements of the repository to load the data.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.repository-populators