# How to create schema in Postgres DB, before liquibase start to work?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, liquibase

I have standalone application. It’s on java, spring-boot, postgres and it has liquibase.

I need to deploy my app and liquibase should create all tables, etc. But it should do it into custom schema not in public. All service tables of liquibase (databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock) should be in custom schema too. How can I create my schema in DB before liquibase start to work? I must do it inside my app when it’s deploying, in config or some like. Without any manual intervention into the DB.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/PostgresDS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_schema
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8

liquibase.change-log = classpath:liquibase/changelog-master.yaml
liquibase.default-schema = my_schema
```

UPD:

When liquibase start, it's create two tables databasechangelogs and one more table. After that, liquibase start working. But I want liquibase in `liquibase.default-schema = my_schema`, but it's not exist when liquibase start to work and it an error: exception is liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: schema "my_schema" does not exist

I want liquibase work in custom schema, not in public:

```
liquibase.default-schema = my_schema
```

but before liquibase can do it, the schema must be created. Liquibase can't do this because it not started yet and for start it needs schema.
Vicious circle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to create my tables(changesets in liquibase will do it) in my custom schema. But when liquibase start to work, my custom schema is not created yet.

Comment: Confused with your two statements "liquibase should create all tables" and "How can I create my schema in DB before liquibase start to work?". two statements are contradictory to each other

Comment: @Rashedul.Rubel liquibase should create tables. Tables in my custom schema, but liquibase can't create schema. I want to create it before liquibase start to work.

Comment: ohh, I misread it. Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can't. When liquibase start, it's create two tables databasechangelogs and one more table. After that, liquibase start working. But I want liquibase in `liquibase.default-schema = my_schema`, but it's not exist when liquibase start to work and it an error: `exception is liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: schema "my_schema" does not exist`

Comment: Please edit your question and include that information; don't use comments to communicate information pertinent to your question.

Comment: So you **do** want the liquibase tables to be created in that schema. Your answer to the first time I asked that question was that you want to create _your_ tables in that schema. You should make creating that schema part of your initial database setup - you are not creating the database in your Liquibase script either, so whatever you use to create the database, that part should also create the needed schema.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want ALL tables in my_schema. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see, but DB is already created. My point is make all changes with DB when my app is deployed . Without manual intervention in the DB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution with my application.properties.

`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils` worked before liquibase.

Logs:

```
14:11:14,760 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils] 
(ServerService Thread Pool -- 300) Executing SQL script from URL 
[vfs:/content/app.war/WEB-INF/classes/schema.sql]

14:11:14,761 INFO  [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils] 
(ServerService Thread Pool -- 300) Executed SQL script from URL 
[vfs:/content/app.war/WEB-INF/classes/schema.sql] in 1 ms.

14:11:14,912 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 300) INFO 9/27/18 
2:11 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock

14:11:15,292 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 300) INFO 9/27/18 
2:11 PM: liquibase: Reading from my_schema.databasechangelog

14:11:15,320 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 300) INFO 9/27/18 
2:11 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

I just put `schema.sql` with `CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema;` into resources dir and all working properly.

Thanks all for help.

**Update**: It's work for Spring boot 1.X. If you are use Spring Boot 2, you should enable schema.sql in properties file, with `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`.
More info in [Spring Boot - Loading Initial Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data)

**Update 2**: In Spring Boot 2.5.2 (maybe in earlier versions too) this solution is not working now, as @peterh has wrote in comment. Sad but true. The last version I was try this solution and it's work was Spring Boot 2.0.9 In docs [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql) says that it was redesigned from Spring Boot 2.5.x

**Update 3**: Some information why they kill this feature -> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22741

Comment: This is good stuff. Unfortunately the Spring Boot 2.x documentation says
 "If you are using a Higher-level Database Migration Tool, like Flyway or Liquibase, you should use them alone to create and initialize the schema. Using the basic `schema.sql` and `data.sql` scripts alongside Flyway or Liquibase is not recommended and support will be removed in a future release." [ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc). So yes, it works .... for now.

Comment: @peterh yes you are right, from the very beginning it was a workaround due to liquibase requires the schema before the initialization. I hope they(lb maintainers) will move the right way and add something to create initial schema before writing databasechangelog

Answer (score 16):

To solve this, we need to run a SQL statement that creates the schema during Spring Boot initialization at the point when `DataSource` bean had been already initialized so DB connections can be easily obtained but before Liquibase runs.

By default, Spring Boot runs Liquibase by creating an `InitializingBean` named `SpringLiquibase`. This happens in `LiquibaseAutoConfiguration`.

Knowing this, we can use `AbstractDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor` to configure `SpringLiquibase` to depend on our custom schema creating bean (`SchemaInitBean` in the example below) which depends on `DataSource`. This arranges the correct execution order.

My `application.properties`:

```
db.schema=my_schema
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=${db.schema}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.liquibase.defaultSchema=${db.schema}
```

Add the `@Configuration` class below to the project, for example put it in a package processed by component scan.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ SpringLiquibase.class, DatabaseChange.class })
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.liquibase", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@AutoConfigureAfter({ DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@Import({SchemaInit.SpringLiquibaseDependsOnPostProcessor.class})
public class SchemaInit {

    @Component
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.liquibase", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
    public static class SchemaInitBean implements InitializingBean {

        private final DataSource dataSource;
        private final String schemaName;

        @Autowired
        public SchemaInitBean(DataSource dataSource, @Value("${db.schema}") String schemaName) {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
            this.schemaName = schemaName;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() {
            try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                 Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
                log.info("Going to create DB schema '{}' if not exists.", schemaName);
                statement.execute("create schema if not exists " + schemaName);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create schema '" + schemaName + "'", e);
            }
        }
    }


    @ConditionalOnBean(SchemaInitBean.class)
    static class SpringLiquibaseDependsOnPostProcessor extends AbstractDependsOnBeanFactoryPostProcessor {

        SpringLiquibaseDependsOnPostProcessor() {
            // Configure the 3rd party SpringLiquibase bean to depend on our SchemaInitBean
            super(SpringLiquibase.class, SchemaInitBean.class);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution does not require external libraries like Spring Boot Pre-Liquibase and not affected by limitations on `data.sql` / `schema.sql` support. My main motivation for finding this solution was a requirement I had that schema name must be a configurable property.
Putting everything in one class and using plain JDBC is for brevity.

Comment: This is perfect, no external libraries for something so specific and no 'schema.sql', something that didn't satisfy me.

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution based on [Pavel D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9061851/pavel-d) answer.
It also can be used without liquibase

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SchemaConfig implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Value("${db.schema}")
    private String schemaName;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(schemaName) && bean instanceof DataSource) {
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) bean;
            try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
                 Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
                log.info("Going to create DB schema '{}' if not exists.", schemaName);
                statement.execute("create schema if not exists " + schemaName);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create schema '" + schemaName + "'", e);
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Spring Boot Pre-Liquibase module](https://github.com/lbruun/Pre-Liquibase) for this. It is exactly what it is meant for. It executes some SQL prior to executing Liquibase itself. Pre-Liquibase sets itself up in the Spring Boot AutoConfigure chain so that it is guaranteed to always execute *before* Liquibase.

#### Step 1

Add the following Starter to your project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.lbruun.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>preliquibase-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>  ---latest-version---  </version>
</dependency>
```

#### Step 2

Add a SQL file to `src/main/resources/preliquibase` with a name of `postgresql.sql` and content like this:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${spring.liquibase.default-schema};
```

The `${}` syntax denotes a placeholder variable. Pre-Liquibase will resolve it from the properties in your Spring Environment.

#### Step 3

Set application properties like this:

```
spring.liquibase.default-schema=${my.db.schemaname}
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=${my.db.schemaname}
```

Now - in this example - the only thing left to decide is where the `my.db.schemaname` value comes from. That is your choice. The [example project](https://github.com/lbruun/Pre-Liquibase/tree/master/example) advocates that it should come from an OS environment variable, in particular if your are deploying to a cloud.

#### Final words

WARNING: Pre-Liquibase is possibly way too flexible in that it allows to execute *any* SQL code. Don't be tempted to put stuff in Pre-Liquibase files which rightfully belong in an Liquibase ChangeSet. Honestly, the only usage I can think of for Pre-Liquibase is to set up a database "home" (meaning a schema or a catalog) where Liquibase db objects can live so that instances of the same application can be separated by schema or catalog while residing on the same database server.

(Disclosure:  I'm the author of Pre-Liquibase module)

Comment: Hi, I can't test it right now, but look nice!

Comment: Beware: using this library may mess with your transaction manager, causing entities to no longer be saved in the database when your application is running...

Comment: @Davio. Sounds odd to me. The library is only active during startup. It doesn't mess with or change any other Spring beans or anything like that.

Comment: I confirm. I have a problem with this lib which disrupts spring initialization.

Answer (score 0):

While the logic from Pavel is correct, the solution is too complex. It's easily solved by having 2 datasources (one for Spring and another for liquibase), and makes the dependent.

Below code is simpler, and it uses a .sql script file. This gives added benefit of creating other DB objects (e.g. functions etc) while creating your schema.

```
@Configuration
public class InitializeDB {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dsUrl;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUser;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dsInitializer(
        @Qualifier("primaryDataSource") final DataSource primaryDataSource) {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator dbPopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        dbPopulator.addScript(
            new ClassPathResource("<your sql scripe path>"));
        DataSourceInitializer dsInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dsInitializer.setDataSource(primaryDataSource);
        dsInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(dbPopulator);
        return dsInitializer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return getDataSource();
    }

    @Bean
    @LiquibaseDataSource
    @DependsOn("dsInitializer")
    public DataSource liquibaseDataSource() {
        return getDataSource();
    }

    private DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder builder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        builder.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        builder.url(dsUrl);
        builder.username(dbUser);
        builder.password(dbPassword);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Logic of this is pretty simple.
When spring loads `dsInitializer`, it first loads `primaryDataSource` which is just Spring DataSource. Once `dsInitializer` bean is created, it initialized the DB with the script provided in it's config.
`liquibaseDataSource` waits for `dsInitializer` to be constructed and complete. Since it's annotated with `@LiquibaseDataSource`, Liquibase use this specific datasource for it's own operation.