# Not able to import sql insert script data from data.sql in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I have a very basic `Spring Boot` application that has `schema.sql` and `data.sql` which creates an `H2` `DB` schema and imports data respectively.

My `schema` is getting generated fine in the `H2 DB` but for some reason data is not getting imported. I see `0` records in the table.

I do not see any errors either.

Looks like a config issue. Please guide.

[image]

pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=500
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/h2-dbs/demo-db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**src/main/resources/schema.sql**

```
drop table env if exists;
create table env (
  id        int             auto_increment      primary key,
  name      varchar(250)    not null            default 'DEV',
  category  varchar(250)    not null            default 'LOWER',
  enabled   char(1)         not null            default 'Y'
);
```

**src/main/resources/data.sql**

```
insert into env (name, category) values
  ('DEV','LOWER'),
  ('QA','LOWER'),
  ('PERF','HIGHER'),
  ('CT','HIGHER'),
  ('UAT','HIGHER'),
  ('PROD','HIGHER');
```

**domain/Env.java**

```
@Entity
public class Env {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private String enabled;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "category")
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    public String getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(String enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Env env = (Env) o;
        return id == env.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, env.name) &&
                Objects.equals(category, env.category) &&
                Objects.equals(enabled, env.enabled);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, category, enabled);
    }
}
```

**EnvRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface EnvRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Env, Integer> {
}
```

**DemoRestApp.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoRestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoRestApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't you handle insert operations within schema.sql as well, after creation of schema? At least; to check if that type of property setting making insert or not ?

Comment: And here, there are more properties suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have this in properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) is more information on that. As you can see, there is note in the documentation which says

> In a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema
>   or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. Make sure to disable
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto if you use schema.sql.