# schema.sql runs whenever the connection is checked

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, schema, mybatis

I am facing a strange issue. 
I have a `schema.sql` file in my springboot application, which creates tables(with foreign key constraints) and inserts data on the application run. But the issue here is, when the connection is idle, then the connection is been tested. Now, this is creating problems for me as `schema.sql` file is again executed and as you know my tables contain foreign key constraints, so the script is failing as it is not allowing to drop the tables which contain foreign key constraints.

Is it because of my `application.properties`?

Here is my **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://dummy_url
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
mybatis.config-location=classpath:/config/mybatis-config.xml
```

Is there any way to make the schema.sql execute only once(only when the application is run)?
My sample `schema.sql` looks this :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t001_map_mst`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `t001_map_mst` (
  `MAP_ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MAP_NAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MAP_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci COMMENT='Contains map info';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`, this property has these values:

> ALWAYS Always initialize the data source.
>   EMBEDDED Only initialize an embedded data source.
>   NEVER Do not initialize the data source.
>   check [official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization)

I provide three ways to solve the problem
1. change your schema.sql, if table exist then don't run the script
2. change your application.properties once you finished your first run, change it to `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=none`
3. init from code: check [Spring Boot - Loading Initial Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data)

Comment: I feel changing my schema is the best way out of all.

Comment: But will be complicated when you want to change your table schema.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: using two sets of configuration files or change just the property is much easier

Comment: I don't think so changing the property from code is possible. or is it possible?