# h2 database is empty when I launch my application with the -jar?

Tags: java, spring, h2

I have an api rest application with an h2 database where I store a user model.
Everything works great when I launch my application directly via intellij or grace mvn spring-boot:run but when I launch the .jar of my application my h2 database looks empty. Maybe I forget a property in my application.properties or something else.
Do you have any idea what the problem is and how to fix it?

there is my application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:Users
spring.h2.console.enable=true
management.security.enable=false
```

and my data.sql file :

```
INSERT INTO user(firstname,lastname, cash, username, password) VALUES('Cristiano' , 'Ronaldo' , 150.5 , 'cr7' , 'realmadrid');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - Loading Initial Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data) See there is an answer with 45 voteups where you can see the application.proptierties.

Comment: Where are the files located in your project? Have you verified that the data.sql ended up in your jar file?