# Can't access API endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

So I've started learning Spring recently by following a small course where we created a market api, when we started we created a simple hello world endpoint to test things out. Recently we just created an endpoint for accessing a list of products, but it seems all requests return a 404 error, since this error seems to be related with the controller I don't think posting all my code is needed.

This is my controller `ProductController.java`, I've only added the mapping for the first two methods (since I'm trying to fix this error still)

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Product> getAll() {
        return productService.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{productId}")
    public Optional<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable("productId") int productId) {
        return productService.getProduct(productId);
    }

    public Optional<List<Product>> getByCategory(int categoryId) {
        return productService.getByCategory(categoryId);
    }

    public Product save(Product product) {
        return productService.save(product);
    }

    public Boolean delete(int productId) {
        return productService.delete(productId);
    }
}
```

I also had to deal with a bean not being found which translated domain objects into dto's (and vise versa) by using [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) with the following error:

*I made sure to annotate my interface with `@Mapper(componentModel="spring")`*

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field mapper in com.platzi.market.persistance.ProductoRepository required a bean of type 'com.platzi.market.persistance.mapper.ProductMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.platzi.market.persistance.mapper.ProductMapper' in your configuration.
```

I managed to fix this with this (source from another student's comment)

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.platzi.market.persistance.mapper.ProductMapper", })
public class PlatziMarketApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlatziMarketApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this **could** be causing some interference with the controller class.

*Are you accessing the correct endpoint?*

This is my `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
server.servlet.context-path=/platzi-market/api
```

And this is the active `dev` profile (`application-dev.properties`)

```
server.port=8080

#  Database, values are altered
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/platzi-market
spring.datasource.username=foo
spring.datasource.password=bar
```

So the endpoint for accesing all product in my controller should be: `localhost:8080/platzi-market/api/products/all` which is returning a 404

I also checked if maybe I am using https so I made sure to use http:// in Postman, which also returned a 404

I double-checked the output in the terminal just to make sure the right port and context-path are being used:

```
2021-02-23 17:20:07.583  INFO 51334 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/platzi-market/api'
2021-02-23 17:20:07.594  INFO 51334 --- [           main] c.platzi.market.PlatziMarketApplication  : Started PlatziMarketApplication in 3.881 seconds (JVM running for 4.296)
```

If you would like to check the rest of the code here's a link to the repo: https://github.com/Je12emy/spring-market-api, hope this makes since since I'm going crazy with error XD

Comment: I'm not a Spring Boot user, but `scanBasePackages` likely wants a _package_ name not a _class_ name.  Should it be `scanBasePackages = { "com.platzi.market.persistance.mapper", }`

Comment: Didn't notice, 1 less thing to worry about, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your problem... (with Eclipse STS 4.9.0).
When running as "Spring boot run configuration" (in eclipse) the context comes up, but with a decent warning. I can reproduce the 404 error pages (due to missing `/error` mapping!).

1. I removed the (useless)`scanBasePackages`, and found the context not starting. (with the described problems).
2. To `build.gradle`, I added:

   ```
    plugins {
      ...
      id "com.diffplug.eclipse.apt" version "3.26.0" // Only for Eclipse
    }
   ```

   ..as described by https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_gradle
3. Then I (recognized, that no mapperImpls were generated,) tried to run via `gradle :bootRun` and found following *generation/"compilation" errors in your mappers*:

   1. In `CategoryMapper` it must be `"description"` *not* `"descripcion"`.
   2. Missing Getter/Setter for `productos` in `Categoria`.
   3. Missing Getter/Setter for `categoria` in `Producto`.

Applying these fixes, (& running (at least initially/every time, when mapper/dto changes) *with gradle*), should* bring up the application and give access to `loclahost:8080/platzi-market/api/products/all`.

*: I "tested" on an empty (different/h2/in-memory) database. (It means, there can be runtime bugs.)

---

A warm welcome to a [spring](/questions/tagged/spring)!

Reviewing your repo, I can recommend you:

- (next) to create some tests (for mappers, repos, controllers ... [code-coverage](/questions/tagged/code-coverage))
- probably [Spring Boot - Loading Initial Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38040572/592355).
- and of course *don't*: expose (real) prod-credentials in public repos. ;)
- ...

Comment: Hello, I just added those changes to the DTO classes and the mapper, but the problems still persists, how can I view the compilation errors from VSCode?. I'll try out Eclipse just to make sure VSCode is not causing any problems. (Hope it isn't since I really like it lol).

Crazy how the error is not being caused by the controller, but the other layers instead I expected to fix this kind of errors when exceptions may be thrown.

PS: Thanks for welcoming me into Spring, really like it over Laravel and dotNet so far!

Comment: Just tried running the application in Eclipse with the same result, could be a database connection error, I'll try out sqllite just to make sure

Comment: you can see the errors, when you start a gradle build (e.g. `./gradlew bootRun` from any IDE/terminal/shell):  `" error: Unknown property "descriction" in result type Categoria. Did you mean "description"?"`

Comment: sql lite in spring boot is [possible](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-sqlite) ... but not as "out of the box" as (e.g.) [h2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database), hsql, ...

Comment: mapstruct in VScode ... you'd have to wait for it: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/

Comment: Just tried `./gradlew bootRun` (I'll be using it more often to catch this kind of errors from now on, tnks), I' try out H2 since it may need less work to implement.