# TestContainers embedded db cannot find tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, testing

I have created a spring boot app with the following setup:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>ticket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ticket</name>
    <description>ticketing microservice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cliftonlabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.playtika.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedded-postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>1.43</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

bootstrap-test.properties:

```
embedded.postgresql.enabled=true
embedded.postgresql.dockerImage=postgres
embedded.postgresql.user=docker
embedded.postgresql.password=docker
embedded.postgresql.schema=test_db
embedded.containers.forceShutdown=true
```

application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${embedded.postgresql.host}:${embedded.postgresql.port}/${embedded.postgresql.schema}
spring.datasource.username=${embedded.postgresql.user}
spring.datasource.password=${embedded.postgresql.password}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

My simple test class:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class TicketControllerTest {


    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void getInfoTest() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/tickets/info",
                String.class)).contains("ghix-ticket");
    }
    @Test
    public void postTicket() throws Exception {
        UserTicket rt = new UserTicket();
        rt.setDetails("Details test");
        rt.setSubject("subject test");
        rt.setCreatedBy("1");
        rt.setCategory("Verify Death");
        rt.setType("Document Verification");
        rt.setRole("2025");
        TkmTickets responseT = this.restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/tickets/",
                rt, TkmTickets.class);
        System.out.println(responseT.getId());
        assertThat(responseT.getDescription()).isEqualTo("Details test");
    }


}
```

Things look good on startup:

```
10:23:46.877 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Activating profiles [test]
10:23:46.881 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}
2021-04-07 10:23:47.419  INFO 27556 --- [           main] EmbeddedPostgreSQLBootstrapConfiguration : Starting postgresql server. Docker image: postgres
2021-04-07 10:23:47.469  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
2021-04-07 10:23:47.833  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.t.d.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy   : Accessing docker with local Unix socket
2021-04-07 10:23:47.833  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
2021-04-07 10:23:47.949  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Docker host IP address is localhost
2021-04-07 10:23:47.991  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 20.10.3
  API Version: 1.41
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 1989 MB
2021-04-07 10:23:48.250  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.t.utility.RegistryAuthLocator          : Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for quay.io
2021-04-07 10:23:48.758  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
2021-04-07 10:23:48.758  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Checking the system...
2021-04-07 10:23:48.759  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : ✔︎ Docker server version should be at least 1.6.0
2021-04-07 10:23:48.865  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : ✔︎ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
2021-04-07 10:23:48.873  INFO 27556 --- [           main]  [postgres:latest]                     : Creating container for image: postgres:latest
2021-04-07 10:23:49.006  INFO 27556 --- [           main]  [postgres:latest]                     : Starting container with ID: 131caba247444daf5c6cc0cff99e8c3ebfc658d53c36d771aeaa2ba6e9bad4c6
2021-04-07 10:23:49.312  INFO 27556 --- [           main]  [postgres:latest]                     : Container postgres:latest is starting: 131caba247444daf5c6cc0cff99e8c3ebfc658d53c36d771aeaa2ba6e9bad4c6
2021-04-07 10:23:50.425  INFO 27556 --- [           main]  [postgres:latest]                     : Container postgres:latest started in PT2.966109S
2021-04-07 10:23:50.426  INFO 27556 --- [           main] EmbeddedPostgreSQLBootstrapConfiguration : Started postgresql server. Connection details: {embedded.postgresql.port=55070, embedded.postgresql.host=localhost, embedded.postgresql.schema=test_db, embedded.postgresql.user=docker, embedded.postgresql.password=docker}, JDBC connection url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:55070/test_db

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-04-07 10:23:50.550  INFO 27556 --- [           main] c.g.ticket.TicketControllerTest          : The following profiles are active: test
2021-04-07 10:23:51.041  INFO 27556 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-07 10:23:51.087  INFO 27556 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 39 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-07 10:23:51.173  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=648ef21c-f385-3b5a-a247-511006c4b8be
2021-04-07 10:23:51.199  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method EmbeddedPostgreSQLDependenciesAutoConfiguration.datasourceDependencyPostProcessor is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2021-04-07 10:23:51.564  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
2021-04-07 10:23:51.574  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-07 10:23:51.575  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-04-07 10:23:52.114  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-07 10:23:52.114  INFO 27556 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1560 ms
2021-04-07 10:23:52.320  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-07 10:23:52.384  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-04-07 10:23:52.524  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-07 10:23:52.619  INFO 27556 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-07 10:23:52.738  INFO 27556 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
```

However shorty after that I see it start to tell me it cannot find the tables in the DB:

```
2021-04-07 10:23:52.778  INFO 27556 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2021-04-07 10:23:52.868  INFO 27556 --- [           main] o.h.e.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl    : Envers integration enabled? : true
2021-04-07 10:23:54.110  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-04-07 10:23:54.111  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "tkm_ticket_tasks" does not exist, skipping
2021-04-07 10:23:54.112  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-04-07 10:23:54.113  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "tkm_ticket_tasks" does not exist, skipping
2021-04-07 10:23:54.114  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-04-07 10:23:54.114  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "tkm_ticket_tasks_aud" does not exist, skipping
2021-04-07 10:23:54.116  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-04-07 10:23:54.116  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "tkm_tickets" does not exist, skipping
2021-04-07 10:23:54.117  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-04-07 10:23:54.117  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "tkm_tickets" does not exist, skipping
2021-04-07 10:23:54.118  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-04-07 10:23:54.118  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "tkm_tickets_aud" does not exist, skipping
2021-04-07 10:23:54.120  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2021-04-07 10:23:54.120  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "tkm_workflows" does not exist, skipping
```

I have a look at the db when debugging and sure enough no tables exist on that postgres container, am I missing something in terms of setup, my understanding was that:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Along with the data in data.sql will be all the setup required to create and populate my tables within the DB container.

Here is my dockerFile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/ghix-ticket-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ghix-ticket-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "ghix-ticket-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

and my dockercompose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    #network_mode: bridge
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker
    restart: unless-stopped
  # This is my rest api app*****************************************
  ghix-ticket:
    image: ghix-ticket
    #network_mode: bridge
    container_name: ghix-ticket
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db/docker
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: docker
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: docker
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /Users/mcerlane_w/dev/:/var/tmp
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

However this is coming from when I am running my tests from IDE or when I run via:

```
mvn test -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=test
```

Log from Postgres container:

```
   The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user 

"postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok
initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.


Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

waiting for server to start....2021-04-07 17:55:15.130 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2021-04-07 17:55:15.131 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-04-07 17:55:15.132 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-04-07 17:55:14 UTC
2021-04-07 17:55:15.134 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

2021-04-07 17:55:15.339 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-04-07 17:55:15.339 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
waiting for server to shut down....2021-04-07 17:55:15.342 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
2021-04-07 17:55:15.342 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
2021-04-07 17:55:15.347 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2021-04-07 17:55:15.459 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2021-04-07 17:55:15.459 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-04-07 17:55:15.460 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-04-07 17:55:15.460 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-04-07 17:55:15.462 UTC [76] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-04-07 17:55:15 UTC
2021-04-07 17:55:15.466 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: You don't have to use Dockerfile but you need to define and pass to Docker container the username, password and database name as parameters

Comment: Please help to share your docker run command

Comment: I've added the dockerfile and docker compose file however this is happening when running via mvn

Comment: Can you check whether the postgres container is up and running and if yes check whether the database is available or not

Comment: I can see the tables however they have not been updated by my data.sql script add container logs

Comment: Where data.sql script resides?

Comment: src/main/resources/data.sql

Comment: How that is supposed to apply to your database? Do you use some schema manager?

Comment: Spring boot should take care of it see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data
I suspect when it tries to run thats when `2021-04-07 10:23:54.111  WARN 27556 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : relation "tkm_ticket_tasks" does not exist, skipping`
gets put out in the logs but only a guess to be honest

Comment: @code_mechanic you're right it's not applying the data.sql, thanks for point me in the right direction!