# Data initialization in Spring Boot Java by Spring DataJPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How can I put initial data in DB after initiating Spring Boot?

I would like to do like this:

1. If `database` already exists, nothing happens.
2. After automatically a database created, which has many tables described in entity files,

I would like to put initial data by certain method like this:

```
@Autowire
UserRepository ur;
 
public void putdata(){
  User u = new User();
   
  ur.save(u);
}
```

The important point is #1 above.
When database already exists, the method must not be called
and not using a SQL file outside.

Comment: Issue query to see if data exists, if so don't do anything... You are probably overthinking this. Also letting Hibernate manage your database through its entities is a bad idea, ideal for rapid prototyping not for use in production!.

Comment: Please read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - Loading Initial Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data). Add your desired condition to `run` method

Comment: ill take the one implementing application runner thank you

Comment: I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72689308/how-to-see-if-spring-boot-initializes-database. please anser it as well