# How to see if Spring Boot initializes database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I would like to put data only when database does not exist on booting Spring boot.

How can I see that?

My application yaml has

...hbm2ddl.auto: update

so I want to see if hibernate did `create tables` or not in Java code.

Comment: i'm sure you can turn some level of logging on for hibernate and look at the log

Comment: To make it clear: you are looking for some kind of event which informs your application that table XYZ has been created?

Comment: If not you could use the auto data import script function which runs on **every** start. That means that all further starts will fail importing the data and throw an exception as they already exists after the first run. To ignore the error set `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true` but IMHO it would be cleaner and easier to use something like liquibase or flyway for Schema updates an initial data import.

Comment: Thanks  you are right. I would see the event about XYZ.. When XYZ is created, I need put some data to empty DB and if not the insertion should be skipped

Comment: now I check some basic tables and count records inside. if the result is not 0 I put. which doesnt seem smart..