# Swagger did not work on real server, how to fix?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu, nginx, swagger-ui

Development machine: Windows 11 pro x64, JDK/Java 19, Spring Boot 2.7.4 .

Real server: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Oracle JDK/Java 19, nginx 1.18.0 .

```
root@vypc:~# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

```
nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/mydomain.com.conf
```

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mydomain.com;

        location / {
             # proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        }
}
```

File `application.properties`

```
server.port=8081

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://103.48.xxx.xxx:5432/fooXXX
spring.datasource.username=MySecretUser
spring.datasource.password=MyScret
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

# Application properties
# https://passwordsgenerator.net/
app.jwtSecret=pXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDegMxYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDepXpYPZ8d8FQv7UDe
app.jwtExpirationMs=86400000

# swagger-ui custom path. Run ok.
# http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.packagesToScan=com.example.controller, com.example.controllers

#logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.root=INFO
# Write logs to the current directory.
logging.file.path=./log

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/49257939/3728901
#spring.sql.init.mode=always
#spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

File

```java
package com.example.security;

import com.example.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.example.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.example.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        // securedEnabled = true,
        // jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                //.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()

                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        //;

       // .addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class); // VyDN 2022_07_22 // https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Real sever

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

result

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.com
103.48.YYY.XXX mydomain.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

103.48.YYY.XXX  vypc.foo.net vypc
```

How to make Swagger working correctly on real server?

Comment: Have you checked there are no errors in the browser console or in the network tab?

Comment: Has error https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/192090837-827ae093-df7b-41b6-85a5-30c72fee3bd6.png and https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/192090974-ea504948-6269-4c77-8877-1c6d139db754.png Seemly due to CORS

Comment: 404...something is missing in target environment, what is available in your DEV..swagger-ui?? (lib/standalone)

Answer (score 1):

Check the files that are linked to from Swagger UI's `index.html`. These are all relative to the `index.html` file itself.

It works on localhost, because there you don't perform any mapping. You access `/swagger-ui/index.html`. That means the browser is trying to load files like `/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js` which works because they are available at that URL.

On nginx, you don't call `/swagger-ui/index.html` but `/`. The files are still relative to this URL. That means the browser is trying to load files like `/swagger-ui-bundle.js`. That's not the correct path for them, so all of the linked files give 404 errors. That's why you don't see anything.

Try mapping `/.*` to `/swagger-ui/.*` (no idea how to do that in nginx). That way, when the browser tries to load `/swagger-ui-bundle.js`, that's mapped to `/swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js` which does exist.

Comment: I am a Java developer, I asked system administrators at https://serverfault.com/q/1111473/243199 I appreciated your idea.