# Connection time-out when access the same H2 file embeded database during test execution

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am creating H2 db in file mode during my Spring-boot application start-up. So is that possible to connect to same db file while running my Serrenity BDD integration API tests?

I took the mixed mode approach specified here [Automatic Mixed Mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html?highlight=server&search=server#auto_mixed_mode)

application.yaml

```
spring:
  cache:
    enabled: false
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:./../myApp/data/ppyDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MODE=Oracle
    username: sa
    password: sa
    baseline-on-migrate: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: false
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none

  flyway:
    enabled: true
    username: sa
    password: sa  
    url: jdbc:h2:./../myApp/data/ppyDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MODE=Oracle
    locations: classpath:/db/h2/migration

  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
```

After the test run I can see new records in the DB

This is the code to connect to same DB during test validation

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM HEADER";

try{

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:./../myApp/data/ppyDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MODE=Oracle");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("sa");
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();

    String metadataValue = "";
    String strMetadata = "test_code";
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    while (rs.next()) {
        metadataValue = strMetadata.isEmpty() || strMetadata.isBlank() ? rs.getString(0) : rs.getString(strMetadata);
    }
    statement.close();
    conn.close();

    Assert.assertEquals(key, "header.approve", metadataValue);
```

DB file actual path : `C:Projects\myApp\data\myDB.mv.db`

SerenityBDD integration tests feature files path : `C:Projects\myApp\api\src\it\resources\`

SerenityBDD integration tests stepDef path : `C:Projects\myApp\api\src\it\java\stepdefs` where the above db access code reside

Main App path: `C:Projects\myApp\api\src\main`

However I can't connect to db using server mode via above test code.

**I am connecting to same H2 file in same machine via two connections**, if that make sense.

Current Error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out: 172.28.308.1:32632" [90067-214]  at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:678)     at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
```

The **myDB.lock.db**

```
#FileLock
#Wed Apr 12 12:39:46 AEST 2023
server=172.28.308.1\:32632
hostName=AULT-D64WVP99.mshome.net
method=file
id=18773536407803de631be7d5c6a327adf2b4a815286
```

I can connect in two windows to DB in embeded mode with this url `jdbc:h2:./../myApp/data/ppyDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MODE=Oracle`

So question here despite be able to connect in two H2 console, why NOT via code? Further to my knowledge and as per docs no need to specify port or IP address (in the lock file) when do a new connection.

Please clarify.

Comment: Apparently timeout error is due to network setup.

Answer (score 0):

H2 file database only allows one connection at at time. you need to reuse existing connection, avoid concurrent connections at all or use H2 in server mode.

Some link to run h2 in server mode: [How to run H2 database in server mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318116/how-to-run-h2-database-in-server-mode)
https://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server

Comment: I used `Automatuc-Mixed-Mode` which can have multiple connections. http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode

Comment: @Shabar Ohhh, great. dunno knew that. definitelly will try it later.