# insertIgnore of Exposed is not inserting data

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jetbrains-ide, insert-update, kotlin-exposed

I have made this table:

```
object PartnerOwnerMappingTable : IntIdTable("partner_owner_mapping") {
  val ownerId = integer("owner_id")
  val driverUUID = uuid("driver_uuid")
  val partnerUUID = uuid("partner_uuid")

  val createdAt = timestampWithoutTZAsInstant("created_at")
  val updatedAt = timestampWithoutTZAsInstant("updated_at")
}
```

And I'm trying to execute this statement using the exposedrepo.

```
PartnerOwnerMappingTable.insertIgnore {
    it[this.ownerId] = record.ownerId
    it[this.driverUUID] = record.driverUUID
    it[this.partnerUUID] = record.partnerUUID
    it[this.createdAt] = Instant.now()
    it[this.updatedAt] = Instant.now()

}
```

But when I'm checking the database the data is not there.

I'm trying to use `insertIgnore` but the data is not reflecting in the database.

Comment: My use case is to insert when ownerid is not present else ignore the value and don't give an error.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example of your code that shows how you connect to the DB and how you handle the transaction or any exceptions. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45520895/18667225