# H2 in-memory test DB closed, despite 'DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, h2

I have some short unit tests that fail with the exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
::
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
::
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-197]
```

The source is my Spring Data AuditProvider, specifically this line:

```
user = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findUserByUsernameAndTenant", User.class)
        .setParameter("tenant", TenantService.DEFAULT_TENANT_ID)
        .setParameter("username", UserService.USER_SYSTEM).getSingleResult();
```

The Error happens **only** when executing the whole test suite, not when running this test class only.

Here the TestRunner I'm using etc:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class MyTest {
```

That's my datasource URL:

```
spring.datasource.url: 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE'
```

So it seems "DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT" doesn't solve the problem, any idea what's happening here?

UPDATE:

I just realized, that this happens only when running the tests in Eclipse, but they run through in the command line. While I do get the occasional:

```
o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL)
```

but I don't get the PersistenceException and stacktrace.

Comment: Be aware the in-memory database is discarded, by default, when the connection closes.  You can override this behavior.  See: [*Keep H2 in-memory database between connections*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/224338/19079) and [*H2 in-memory database. Table not found*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5763747/642706)

Answer (score 17):

## Use `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` only.

For in-memory database, you shouldn't use `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`: you should only use `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases

So you datasource should be:

```
spring.datasource.url: 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1'
```

It is also possible that your unit tests are executed in parallel processes. Make sure that they all run in the same VM.

If you use Maven, set `forkCount` to `0`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I tested it with your suggestions. I've changed the connection string and added the plugin config. It didn't change anything. I ran the tests in the commandline and they work, see my edit above. :/ (for clarification: they work with or without forkCount=0 and in Eclipse they always get marked failed for the exception)

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer Sorry for you. Unfortunately I have no clue as to why the integration in Eclipse is so different from the usual Maven build. This is mostly why I use either Netbeans or IntelliJ: their integration with Maven or Gradle is way better.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire it is not true that you shouldn't use `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` see [the doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-embedded-database-support) - _If, for whatever reason, you do configure the connection URL for an embedded database, take care to ensure that the database’s automatic shutdown is disabled._

Answer (score 4):

I guess your various unit test classes are all annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` ?

If so, every started test class will boot Spring which will in turn boot JPA.
If **multiple** tests classes are run in parallel, each of them creating, then dropping, the **SAME** in-memory database, you might have some concurrency issues.

You may also have to set surefire `reuseForks` parameter to false in order to prevent JUnit from reusing the same 'context' for **consecutive** tests

Comment: Sorry, I added that missing detail. This test uses the SpringRunner and most of them are, as these are our Integration Tests.