# Spring boot test throws JdbcException "table not found"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have application-test.properties where I defined two datasources

```
    app.datasource.server.url=jdbc:h2:mem:fooserver
    app.datasource.server.username=sa
    app.datasource.server.password=
    app.datasource.server.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    app.datasource.server.hikari.minimumIdle=5
    app.datasource.server.hikari.maximumPoolSize=50
    app.datasource.server.hikari.idleTimeout=50000
    app.datasource.server.hikari.maxLifetime=55000


    app.datasource.manager.url=jdbc:h2:mem:barmanager
    app.datasource.manager.username=sa
    app.datasource.manager.password=
    app.datasource.manager.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    app.datasource.manager.hikari.minimumIdle=5
    app.datasource.manager.hikari.maximumPoolSize=50
    app.datasource.manager.hikari.idleTimeout=50000
    app.datasource.manager.hikari.maxLifetime=55000


    # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop


    #logging
    logging.level.root=info
    logging.file=foobar-rest-test.log

    #required for SpringBootTest does not know why
    spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Each of the datasource requires schema to be available named "foo" this will be created by a schema-fooserver.sql and schema-barmanager.sql in each of these sql scripts the foo schema will be created. Therefore I defined a dataSourceIntializer Bean where I can define which schema-sql file will be loaded.

```
@Bean(name = "managerDataSourceInitializer")
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer1(@Qualifier("managerDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema-barmanager.sql"));        

    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}



@Bean(name = "serverDataSourceInitializer")
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer1(@Qualifier("serverDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
    ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema-fooserver.sql"));

    DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(datasource);
    dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
    return dataSourceInitializer;
}
```

During the start of my test the logs show that these schema files have been called and executed.

```
    2019-03-28 15:04:34.252 DEBUG 3124 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [schema-fooserver.sql]
    2019-03-28 15:04:34.252 DEBUG 3124 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS FOO
    2019-03-28 15:04:34.252 DEBUG 3124 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [schema-fooserver.sql] in 0 ms.


    2019-03-28 15:04:34.252 DEBUG 3124 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [schema-barserver.sql]
    2019-03-28 15:04:34.252 DEBUG 3124 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS FOO
    2019-03-28 15:04:34.252 DEBUG 3124 --- [main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [schema-barserver.sql] in 0 ms.
```

Now when I try to execute my test case it fails because of the following error:

```
    28 15:04:36.035 DEBUG 3124 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into foo.Account (uid, password_hash, login) values (null, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into foo.Account (uid, password_hash, login) values (null, ?, ?)
    2019-03-28 15:04:36.036 DEBUG 3124 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : could not prepare statement [insert into foo.Account (uid, password_hash, login) values (null, ?, ?)]

    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Tabelle "ACCOUNT" nicht gefunden
    Table "ACCOUNT" not found; SQL statement:
    insert into foo.Account (uid, password_hash, login) values (null, ?, ?) [42102-197]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
```

At this point I am trying to create a UserAccount in my testcase

This is the defined UerEntity

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "foo.Account")
    public class UserEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "uid")
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "login")
        private String username;
        @Column(name = "password_hash")
        private String password;
 ....
```

Here is the Testcase. The error occurs when the before mehod is called during the createUser Method.

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @AutoConfigureMockMvc
    public class UserControllerTest {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserControllerTest.class);

        @LocalServerPort
        private int port;
        TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        @Autowired
        private WfcSpringRestApplication controller;

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository repository;

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mvc;

        private AuthenticationToken authToken;

        @Before
        public void before() throws Exception {
            headers = new HttpHeaders();
            UserEntity user = createTestUser(TEST_ADMIN_USER, TEST_ADMIN_MD5_PW, UserRight.ADMIN);
            UserEntity userService = createTestUser(TEST_SERVICE_USER, TEST_ADMIN_MD5_PW, UserRight.SERVICE);
            getAuthenticationTokenForTestUser(user);

        }


        private UserEntity createTestUser(String username, String md5_password, UserRight right) {

            UserEntity ue = new UserEntity();
            ue.setUsername(username);
            ue.setPassword(md5_password);

            UserRole roleAdmin = new UserRole();
            roleAdmin.setRight(right);

            ue.getRoles().put(roleAdmin.getRight(), roleAdmin);

            repository.save(ue);

            return ue;
        }


        @Test
        public void contextLoads() {
            assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
        }
```

In the error message there is the correct table name "could not prepare statement [insert into foo.Account" why it throws the exception that the table account is not found?

Comment: Have you checked whether the table is created before running the test?

Comment: I'd suggest you to mark anyone of the datasource bean as primary using `@Primary` annotation and try.

Comment: its in memory datasource, I was not able to check this. I debugged it before the exception and connected to the datasource but could not find the schema or the table

Comment: The first one is marked as primary in my configuration class for the datasources

Comment: Even though its a in memory database, you can access it thru  <hostname>/h2-console

Comment: Another thing to check is the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property. Have you tried changing it to create rather than create-drop?

Comment: Yes I have tried both spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto settings

Comment: Try to set table's name without the schema:                                                          @Table(name = "Account")
public class UserEntity

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar error and I tried pretty much every solution mentioned on other websites such as DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1; DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE; IGNORECASE=TRUE

But nothing worked for me.

For Spring Boot 2.4+ use **spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true** in application.properties (mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68086707/8219358)

Another way that worked for me was renaming data.sql to import.sql

I found it here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53179547/8219358

I realize other solutions are more logical but none of them worked for me and this did.

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution that worked for me.  I tried spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true and spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create, both didn't work