# @DataJpaTest Table not found on flush spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Environment:

MS SQL Server environment
  JDK 8

Converting Spring Boot 2 to JPA using H2 for integration tests.

application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb

spring.datasource.username=sa

spring.datasource.password=

spring.h2.console.enabled: false

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStategyStandardImpl

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Entity:

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "ref_application")

@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

public class Application {



    @Id

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "uuid2", parameters = {})

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")

    @Column(name = "app_id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")

    private String appId;



    @Column(name = "app")

    @NotNull

    private String appName;



    @Column(name = "description")

    @NotNull

    private String description;



    @Column(name="sys_create_tm")

    @NotNull

    @CreatedDate

    private LocalDateTime createTm;



    @Column(name="created_by", columnDefinition="varhcar(150) default 'ORION'")

    @NotNull

    @CreatedBy

    private String createdBy;



    @Column(name="updated_at")

    @Null

    @LastModifiedDate

    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;



    @Column(name="updated_by")

    @Null

    @LastModifiedBy

    private String updatedBy;
```

Repository:

```
@Repository

@EnableJpaAuditing

public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, String> {



    //JPQL syntax

    @Query("SELECT ra from Application ra where ra.appName = :appName")

    Application findByAppName(@Param("appName") String appName);

}
```

Test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@DataJpaTest     //Autoconfigures H2 by default and runs app context

public class ApplicationRepositoryTests {



    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationRepositoryTests.class);



    @Autowired

    private ApplicationRepository appRepository;



    @Autowired

    private EntityManager entityManager;



    @Autowired

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;



    @Test

    //@Sql({"/import_applications.sql"})

    public void whenFindByAppName_thenReturnApp() {

        try {



            Application app = new Application();

            app.setAppName("TVP");

            app.setDescription("TEST Description");

            app.setCreateTm(LocalDateTime.now());

            app.setCreatedBy("whenFindByAppName_thenReturnApp");

            appRepository.save(app);

            LOG.debug("*************** flush()");

            appRepository.flush();



            LOG.debug("*************** findByAppName()");

            Application dbApp = appRepository.findByAppName("TVP");

            LOG.info("dbAPP:: " + dbApp);

            assertThat(dbApp).isNotNull();

        } catch(Exception e) {

            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);

            fail(e.getMessage());

        }

    }
```

Results:

```
Hibernate: drop table ref_application if exists

13:41:11.180 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - drop table ref_user_group if exists

Hibernate: drop table ref_user_group if exists

13:41:11.210 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table ref_application (app_id uniqueidentifier not null, app varchar(255) not null, sys_create_tm timestamp not null, created_by varhcar(150) default 'ORION' not null, description varchar(255) not null, updated_at timestamp, updated_by varchar(255), primary key (app_id))

Hibernate: create table ref_application (app_id uniqueidentifier not null, app varchar(255) not null, sys_create_tm timestamp not null, created_by varhcar(150) default 'ORION' not null, description varchar(255) not null, updated_at timestamp, updated_by varchar(255), primary key (app_id))

13:41:11.220 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.EnumType - Using ORDINAL-based conversion for Enum gov.dhs.tsa.tvu.bo.TvuStatus

13:41:11.221 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - create table ref_user_group (ref_user_group_id uniqueidentifier not null, address varchar(255), city varchar(255), sys_create_dt timestamp not null, created_by varchar(255) not null, description varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, group_code varchar(255) not null, phone varchar(255) not null, poc varchar(255) not null, state varchar(255), status integer, display_ui boolean not null, updated_at timestamp, updated_by varchar(255), zip varchar(255), app_id uniqueidentifier, primary key (ref_user_group_id))

Hibernate: create table ref_user_group (ref_user_group_id uniqueidentifier not null, address varchar(255), city varchar(255), sys_create_dt timestamp not null, created_by varchar(255) not null, description varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, group_code varchar(255) not null, phone varchar(255) not null, poc varchar(255) not null, state varchar(255), status integer, display_ui boolean not null, updated_at timestamp, updated_by varchar(255), zip varchar(255), app_id uniqueidentifier, primary key (ref_user_group_id))

13:41:11.238 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - alter table ref_user_group add constraint FKij5uhedc20orc8a8f3yk9vatu foreign key (app_id) references ref_application

13:52:32.473 [main] TRACE o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope - Handling #sessionFactoryCreated from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@73d292e9] for TypeConfiguration

13:52:32.506 [main] INFO  gov.dhs.tsa.tvu.TvuApplication - TvuApplication running in UTC timezone: 2020-03-16T19:52:32.506

13:52:34.073 [main] INFO  g.d.t.t.r.ApplicationRepositoryTests - Started ApplicationRepositoryTests in 14.469 seconds (JVM running for 22.27)

13:52:34.402 [main] DEBUG g.d.t.t.r.ApplicationRepositoryTests - *************** flush()

13:52:34.595 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

13:52:34.599 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table "REF_APPLICATION" not found; SQL statement:

insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]

13:52:34.624 [main] ERROR g.d.t.t.r.ApplicationRepositoryTests - could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)

        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)

        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)

        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)

        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)

        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)

        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.flush(Unknown Source)

        at gov.dhs.tsa.tvu.repository.ApplicationRepositoryTests.whenFindByAppName_thenReturnApp(ApplicationRepositoryTests.java:83)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)

        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)

        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)

        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)

        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)

        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)

        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)

        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)

        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)

        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)

        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)

        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)

        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)

        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)

        at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)

        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)

        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)

        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)

        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)

        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)

        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)

        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)

        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)

        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)

        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)

        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)

        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)

        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)

        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)

        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)

        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)

        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)

        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)

        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)

        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)

        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)

        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)

        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "REF_APPLICATION" not found; SQL statement:

insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]

        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)

        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)

        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)

        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)

        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628)
```

insert into ref_application
Table "REF_APPLICATION" not found

Doesn't work with @Table(name = "REF_APPLICATION")

naming-strategy property didn't fix it.

Same issue when removing flush. Exception occurs on findByAppName

Same issue using @Sql({"/import_applications.sql"})

UPDATE

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
```

```
04:48:27.821 [main] INFO  g.d.t.t.r.ApplicationRepositoryTests - Started ApplicationRepositoryTests in 13.727 seconds (JVM running for 20.265)

04:48:28.418 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (? ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

04:48:28.421 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table "REF_APPLICATION" not found; SQL statement:

insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]

[ERROR] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 4, Time elapsed: 15.02 s <<< FAILURE! - in gov.dhs.tsa.tvu.repository.ApplicationRepositoryTests

[ERROR] saveApp  Time elapsed: 0.135 s  <<< ERROR!

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, dscription, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statment

        at gov.dhs.tsa.tvu.repository.ApplicationRepositoryTests.saveApp(ApplicationRepositoryTests.java:65)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

        at gov.dhs.tsa.tvu.repository.ApplicationRepositoryTests.saveApp(ApplicationRepositoryTests.java:65)

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException:

Table "REF_APPLICATION" not found; SQL statement:

insert into ref_application (app, sys_create_tm, created_by, description, updated_at, updated_by, app_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-200]

        at gov.dhs.tsa.tvu.repository.ApplicationRepositoryTests.saveApp(ApplicationRepositoryTests.java:65)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your datasource url to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
```

H2 is in memory DB and as soon as tables get created it closes the connection and changes are discarded. Take a look here: [H2 in-memory database. Table not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763747/h2-in-memory-database-table-not-found/17925668#17925668)

But your main problem is typos:

- naming strategy should be set to org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
- column definition for createdBy has wrong type (should be @Column(name="created_by", columnDefinition="varchar(150) default 'ORION'"))

Comment: Thanks Adam. Strange place for a property value. Unfortunately, I did not work.

Comment: Same exception as before?

Comment: I updated my answer - you have a problem with typos

Comment: Many thanks for finding my typos and alleviating some job stress. I had found the property one but missed the column definition.